# Forbidden 403 - Prefeitura Curitiba

Tags: php

Estou tendo problemas ao conectar na prefeitura de Curitiba usando o CURL.

Código

```
$tamanho = strlen($xml_envio);
$parametros = array(
                        'POST /Iss.NfseWebService/nfsews.asmx HTTP/1.1',
                        'Host: isscuritiba.curitiba.pr.gov.br',
                        'Content-Type: application/soap+xml;charset=utf-8',
                        "Content-length: $tamanho");

$oCurl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($oCurl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 1 );
curl_setopt($oCurl, CURLOPT_URL,$this->URLwebservice[$this->aplicativo]);
curl_setopt($oCurl, CURLOPT_PORT, 443);
curl_setopt($oCurl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
curl_setopt($oCurl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1); //retorna o cabeçalho de resposta
curl_setopt($oCurl, CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE, CURL_IPRESOLVE_V4);
curl_setopt($oCurl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2); // verifica o host evita MITM
curl_setopt($oCurl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($oCurl, CURLOPT_SSLCERT, $this->certKEY); // cnpj_certKey.pem
curl_setopt($oCurl, CURLOPT_SSLKEY, $this->priKEY); // cnpj_privKey.pem
curl_setopt($oCurl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($oCurl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml_envio);
curl_setopt($oCurl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($oCurl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $parametros);
$xml = curl_exec($oCurl);
```

Se mando sem o certificado a prefeitura responde que falta o certificado, se mando com o certificado volta `FORBIDDEN 403`.

Observação: O certificado é válido e não está vencido.

Comment: O que é o $this ? Eu utilizo os serviços do ISS de curitiva com a classe guzzle, de uma olhada nesse método: http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/request-options.html#cert

Comment: $this é o atrai que contém os valores. $this->URLwebservice[$this->aplicativo] é o endereço do ES. Vc pode me enviar com o vc usa a classe ?

Comment: Não consegui gerar um cert de teste novo no site do piloto (aquilo é horrivel), mas é algo como isso: https://ideone.com/Avg4a9